# D3.js force-directed graph from a JSON data file - not showing any nodes

Tags: javascript, json, html, d3.js

I am a newbie in D3JS and I was trying to do a similar example to this one : http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045

I have generated this JSON file `output.json` and I try to get it running but nothing shows up!

```
{"nodes":[{"name":"Hiroyasu Nakata","group":1},{"name":"Kazuo Satoh","group":1},{"name":"Tyuzi Ohyama","group":1},{"name":"Yasufumi Fujiwara","group":1},{"name":"Youichi Nonogaki","group":1},{"name":"Yoshikazu Takeda","group":1},{"name":"N. Tamari","group":2},{"name":"S. H. Wemple","group":3},{"name":"Kun-Jing Lee","group":4},{"name":"Z. C. Huang","group":4},{"name":"J. C. Chen","group":4},{"name":"L. Cai","group":5},{"name":"S. Han","group":5},{"name":"G. May","group":5},{"name":"S. Kamra","group":5},{"name":"T. Krygowski","group":5},{"name":"A. Rohatgi","group":5},{"name":"Stephen Miller","group":7},{"name":"Paul H. Holloway","group":7}],"links":[{"source":1,"target":2},{"source":1,"target":3},{"source":1,"target":4},{"source":1,"target":5},{"source":1,"target":6},{"source":2,"target":3},{"source":2,"target":4},{"source":2,"target":5},{"source":2,"target":6},{"source":3,"target":4},{"source":3,"target":5},{"source":3,"target":6},{"source":4,"target":5},{"source":4,"target":6},{"source":5,"target":6},{"source":9,"target":10},{"source":9,"target":11},{"source":10,"target":11},{"source":12,"target":13},{"source":12,"target":14},{"source":12,"target":15},{"source":12,"target":16},{"source":12,"target":17},{"source":13,"target":14},{"source":13,"target":15},{"source":13,"target":16},{"source":13,"target":17},{"source":14,"target":15},{"source":14,"target":16},{"source":14,"target":17},{"source":15,"target":16},{"source":15,"target":17},{"source":16,"target":17},{"source":18,"target":19}]}
```

This is the HTML file :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .charge(-120)
    .linkDistance(30)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

d3.json("output.json", function(error, graph) {
  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("r", 5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("title")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
  });
});

</script>
```

What did I do wrong? And how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: It'd probably help to see what you've written…

Comment: Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Nothing! Just a blank page!

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? Are some of the DOM nodes being created? Does `console.log(graph.nodes)` and `console.log(graph.links)` print what you expect?

Comment: It looks like your node indices in the links are 1 and not 0 based. Indices in Javascript start with 0. Subtract 1 from all links and it should work fine.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Looks like a great idea! How can I do that?

Comment: @meetamit The console has shown this error message `TypeError: r.target is undefined
...r.target=m[r.target]),++r.source.weight,++r.target.weight;for(t=0;c>t;++t)r=m[t]...` The error is located in the `d3.js` lib file

Comment: You would need to fix this in whatever you're using to generate the JSON.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff OK! That can be done! But, is there anyway to fix it in the Javascript?

Comment: Well iterate over the nodes and subtract 1 from source and target.